# Recurring Email in Outlook, fully automatic and no user interaction

Tags: vbscript

I've been trying to figure out how to do the following in MS Outlook 2016

- Send a weekly prepopulated email, with updated dates in the body
- The email has an updated .pptx file (directory can be static)
- Outlook could be open for the application to run, but preferably not
- There is no user interaction besides updating the .pptx within the directory

I've played with the below Macro, right now it is reliant on dismissing a notification related to a calendar notification to send the email (regardless if the notification is set to none).

Has anyone done anything similar/ offer advice?

```vb
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim MItem As MailItem
Set MItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then Exit Sub
If Item.Categories <> "Send_att_recurring_email" Then Exit Sub
MItem.To = "user@gmail.com"
MItem.CC = "otherUser@gmail.com"

MItem.Subject = Item.Subject
MItem.Body = Item.Body
With MItem
.Attachments.Add "<C:\Desktop\Documents\Agenda.docx>"
.Display

End With
```

Comment: You might want to include an actual question in your "question"

Comment: If you want this to work without outlook being open, then you can't build it in outlook. You would need to build an actual vbscript and then have it scheduled through Windows Scheduler to execute each week. It would have to be running on a computer that was powered on when you want that scheduled run to occur.